# Apex:include should only rendered When onclick event occurs

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm having a page Say VFPage1 with class apex1

In my page2, my code is something like this

var arr = document.getElementById("contactandaccount");
 alert(arr); //getting null here

```
<apex:define name="sidebar">
       <div id="sidebar">
           <ul style="display: block;" class="leftnav nav ">
            <li class="submenu1 active"><a href="#account" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span> Accounts</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#contactandaccount" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon icon-tasks"></i> <span>Contacts and Accounts</span> </a></li></ul>
              <div id="account" class="tab-pane">
                    <apex:include pageName="formtemplate" style="display-none;"/>
            </div>
            <div id="contactandaccount">
                 <apex:include pageName="Includetemplate" style="display-none;"/>
             </div>    
        </div>
     </div>
  </apex:define> 
</apex:page>
```

[image]

When I click on `API Accounts` VFPage1 should be displayed.Similarly for the other tabs also.I want a individual Vf Page and class should get displayed for each object(i.e., for api accounts,Contacts,Opportunities etc) But here nothing get displayed
What was the mistake I'm doing here

Comment: The apex:include is enclosed with your <a> </a> HTML anchor tabs. This is not what you want. Are you wanting to navigate to page VFPage1 when they click on the link? <apex:include> is not the way to achieve this.

Comment: @DougB then What would be the solution for this? Added an Image in my Question.So please suggest a solution based on my requirement

Comment: It sounds like you want tabs, and when you click on a particular tab then you get information which is already defined on a VF page. In that case you may want to consider using an <apex:tabPanel> and then within that you would have an <apex:tab> which used <apex:include> to bring in the content you wanted.

Comment: Here we are not going to use Tab System(That is previously used).Client requirement is as shown in the Image.So I guess by using html I need to use Includepage and make it work

Comment: Well then maybe wrap the <apex:include> in a div, and use javascript to show/hide the div?

Comment: ok vl give a try.Any example on this pls

Comment: Something like this, setup divs for each page, the hidden section would look something like this <div id='APIAccountsTab' style='display:none;'><apex:include pageName="VFPage1" /></div> Then you would show it by changing the style of the div to display:block using javascript in response to the user clicking on the tab heading.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use {!} within your rendered attribute. So:

```
<apex:include pageName="VFPage1" rendered="{!apiaccount}"/>
```

or

```
<apex:include pageName="VFPage1" rendered="{!apiaccount == true}"/>
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in this list. If you want to make a clickable item in a list using Visualforce, try something like this instead:

```
<apex:outputText value="API Accounts">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!clickMethod}" rerender="outerBlock"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

where clickMethod is an Apex method that does something like toggle the value of apiaccount, and outerBlock is the block of *Visualforce* that is surrounding the area that you want optionally rendered. Or you can omit this part and the entire page will get refreshed:

```
<apex:outputText value="API Accounts">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!clickMethod}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: ....also the include is inside the <a> </a> tags so if it does render it will try and show the entire second page as a single hyperlink!

Comment: True! I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

it may be you have set apiaccount in controller to false